# SQL: How to Generate a Unique ID given table full of FirstName_LastName### fields

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a list of ID's like "FIRST_LAST" format.

And I have the "main" table with a bunch of FIRST_LAST## entries where ## is some number. I am trying to find the last un-used name and number being used.

Sample usage: I have John_Smith but I don't know how many John Smiths are in the main table. There is a John_Smith1, John_Smith2, etc in the main table, but I want to know the first available one. So I have John_Smith and I want to be able to scan it against the table and see that John_Smith8 is the first un-used name in the main table.

Please let me know if I am not making sense.

Comment: Is it too late in your design process to make these separate data fields?

Comment: Yes, the main table is more or less set in stone

Comment: Is it too late to design your table to have first_name, last_name and a surrogate autogenerated ID field?  This will never be efficeint, the possibility of runtime problems is high and there is no need to do such a thing when you design properly.  Names will never be unique, so adding numbers to them to make them unique just makes it harder to query them. Use a surrogate key.This truly is an unworkable design.

Comment: @HLGEM I have 0 influence over this. I have to work with what I have. I can't go hacking away and telling them that they need to overhaul their entire system at this point in time.

Comment: My answer below will generate a unique ID. I would also suggest renaming this question. The title doesn't really match what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnKroetch I am using MS Access. It matches what I am asking because I'd like to say something like "return the last entry from main-table where it's like the entry from my list"

Comment: Oh -- didn't see that in your question. I see it's tagged, though. I missed that. Can you take my answer below and 'MS Access-ify' it?

Answer (score 1):

The following VBA function might prove helpful:

```
Public Function GetNextFirstLastID(first_last As String) As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, nextN As Long
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT Max(CLng(Mid(first_lastID, " & Len(first_last) + 1 & "))) " & _
        "FROM mainTable " & _
        "WHERE first_lastID LIKE """ & first_last & "#*""", _
        dbOpenSnapshot)
If IsNull(rst(0).Value) Then
    nextN = 1
Else
    nextN = rst(0).Value + 1
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
GetNextFirstLastID = first_last & nextN
End Function
```

For test data like this...

```
first_lastID   
---------------
gord_thompson1 
gord_thompson11
gord_thompson2 
gord_thom1
```

...the function returns

```
?GetNextFirstLastID("gord_thompson")
gord_thompson12
?GetNextFirstLastID("gord_thom")
gord_thom2
?GetNextFirstLastID("john_smith")
john_smith1
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Don George. The design here is flawed for what you are trying to do. If you can, go back and break FIRST into it's own data field, and then LAST as it's own field. There should be a unique auto-incrementing ID for each new entry, and that should be the key into that record. If you want to know how many "John Smiths" there are, then you can simply do a `COUNT()`

---

If you cannot do this, then a very poorly performing attempt is to create a SQL loop with an incrementing counter:

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 1

DECLARE @name nchar(100)
SET @name = 'john_smith' + CAST(@counter AS nchar(4))

WHILE (Exists(Select * From MainTable WHERE ID = @name ))
BEGIN
   SET @counter = @counter + 1
   SET @name = 'john_smith' + CAST(@counter AS nchar(4))
END

-- Now you have your @name to use...
```

---

From a design standpoint, and if this is your only option, I'd create a function called `GetUniqueID(FIRST, LAST)` that returns the unique ID. It would perform this function above.

You can then stub in any better-performing SQL code later.